# Tamper system calls behavior with QEMU

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, qemu

I don't know if this is the right place, but I don't know where I could ask.
I'd like to change the system call behavior inside QEMU (or even inside the kernel if I can make this modification temporary), for instance if I call the read(fd) call, I would like to hook for this call and maybe change the file descriptor or the content itself.
I would like to have a general structure like this, maybe by using a plugin or I don't know what:

```
syscall_interceptor(syscall, syscall_parameters){
    new_parameters = tamper(syscall_parameters)
    syscall(new_parameters )
}
```

something like that. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Is this question about x64 acrhitecture? Is it about QEMU emulation mode (TCG accelerator)?

Comment: @nevilad yes, it is about x64 architecture, and yes, I am talking about QEMU emulation and TCG. I guess I could write a plugin, but if I am correct, I can only intercept the call, but not tamper it

Comment: You can do this kind of thing with ptrace, without involving QEMU at all, if that would work for you. QEMU itself doesn't provide any mechanism for this.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem with qemu, you can change the `syscall` handler for x64 TCG mode. It's a function named `helper_syscall` in `qemu\target\i386\seg_helper.c` source file. You need the second one (`#else` branch of `#if defined(CONFIG_USER_ONLY)`). After changing the code you have to build qemu.

According to [this](https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) a sys_read syscall should have:
rax = 0, rdi = fd, rsi = buf, rdx = count.

You can add the changes at the top of the handler:

```
void helper_syscall(CPUX86State *env, int next_eip_addend)
{
    int selector;

    if (0 == env->regs[R_EAX]) {
      //sys_read syscall
      //env->regs[R_EDI] - fd, change it, to change fd value:
      // env->regs[R_EDI] = newFd;
      //env->regs[R_ESI] - buf pointer
      //env->regs[R_EDX] - count

      //To rewrite buf contents, use cpu_memory_rw_debug
      //and set write address to rsi:
      //CPUState *cpu = env_cpu(env);
      //if (cpu_memory_rw_debug(cpu, env->regs[R_ESI], 
      //                     (uint8_t *)&newContents, newContents size, 1))
      //{
      //  handle buf write error here.
      //}
    }
    .....
```

See comments in the code snippet and dont forget to check buffer size before you rewrite the buffer.